# AWS API Gateway custom URL parameter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway

Setting up API Gateway with web-sockets I want embedded hardware clients reporting to this web-socket (aka the WebSocket URL). Sadly this clients are preconfigured and add their "ID" as part of the URL (see example below).

Is there any way I can extract the ID and manage it within the consecutive processing? I need the URL to identify my different clients and make appropriate responses.

WebSocket URL: `wss://12dxxxxx.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev/<THIS_IS_THE_ID_OF_MY_EMBEDDED_HARDWARE>`

Comment: a workaround would be just splitting the API string by "/" and pick the first element after the stage part.

Comment: But API Gateway is not even accepting the connection

Answer (score 3):

A workaround would be to use CloudFront distribution in front of the websocket API and serve the requests via CloudFront distribution. Meaning custom domain name can be created for websocket API that will be served via CloudFront dist. The origin of the CloudFront dist would be the websocket API endpoint

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/amazon-cloudfront-announces-support-for-the-websocket-protocol/

Lambda@Edge function can be triggered on 'Origin Request' event and the function can strip the hardware id from the URL and pass it as queryString or header etc to the websocket API. The backend of the websocket API can access queryString/header and eventually get hardware id from the incoming event data

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-cloudfront-trigger-events.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-redirecting-examples

Note: DNS record(CNAME) is required to map the Domain Name to CloudFront dist

Sample L@E nodeJs code below:

```js
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log(event)
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    var hardwareId = request.uri.substr(1);

    request.origin = {
                 custom: {
                     domainName: 'xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
                     port: 443,
                     protocol: 'https',
                     path: '/dev',
                     sslProtocols: ['TLSv1', 'TLSv1.1','TLSv1.2'],
                     readTimeout: 60,
                     keepaliveTimeout: 5,
                     customHeaders: {}
                }
    };

    request.uri = '/';

    request.querystring = 'hardwareId='+hardwareId;

    callback(null, request);
};
```

Comment: Clever workaround thanks for the idea. I, this is adding another service I would still leave it unanswered and just vote you up. Hopefully this feature will be added to API Gateway itself.

Comment: Indeed a good way to achieve that. In order to the above workaround work, make sure you create a custom domain at your API Gateway console/API and then you should point this custom domain DNS to it's endpoint directly (not to the execute-api url on the stage) and in the CloudFront origin, you can keep the '/' instead of proposed '/dev' as the custom domain will be automatically designated to a stage (dev in the example above). You then don't need to replace the `request.origin` but only the `request.uri` as in the example above. Hope it helps others in the future!